# How to connect remote server with web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, entity-framework, remote-server

I want to connect remote server via web service written by me.

I am using Entity Framework in my application to connect database. Is Entity Framework has any base to connect remote server or web servise infrastructure?

How to do this?

Can you give me any advice?

Please, Could you help me on this situation?

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework supports anything your connection string will give you access to.

Comment: Like I write the server address inside the webconfig?

Comment: @saul yeah, if your db has given remote access

Comment: So when i write the web config i can access the remote server to get their data with my web service? Or is there any requirment web sevice?

Comment: it supports standard DB connectivity only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696589/connection-string-to-remote-db-when-using-entityframework

Comment: Than you @Nikos I thing this link will help me